# Loop guard optimization

Tags: javascript, programming-languages

A number of years ago I read a very simple article about loop optimization. In particular, if you have to iterate over a list in Java you can put the guard in the initialization in order to avoid a method call in each iteration:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i)
```

becomes:

```
for (int i = 0, len = list.size(); i < len; ++i)
```

Now, I'm working with Javascript where the Array lenght is stored in a variable. So, I was wondering if there is a difference between:

```
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; ++i)
```

and:

```
for (int i = 0, len = list.length; i < len; ++i)
```

Moreover, I read that prefix increment is preferred since it doesn't evaluate to the value of the expression, right?

Comment: You could try with a profiler and see if there's an actual difference.

Comment: See this performance test: http://jsben.ch/wo39o

Comment: “since it doesn't evaluate to the value of the expression”—if `++i` doesn’t evaluate to the value of the expression, to what does it evaluate then? The only difference between `++i` and `i++` is that the former evaluates to the new value and the latter evaluates to the old value of `i`, neither being used when using it as a statement. Why should that have an impact on the performance?